# Attribute from php to Jquery.click within php foreach

Tags: php, jquery, json, foreach

I've been trying out different things for a while, but nothing seems to be working. And would probably need another kind of perspective.

For the question: I got a php foreach loop going, and every object is posting the ID of that object.

But my problem in this that when i click, the object is giving me the last number of the foreach.
Ive been trying to post the value in JSON, and just plain php.

PHP

```
<?php
foreach ($places as $place) {
    $place_id = json_encode($place['id']);
    echo "<div class='placeContainer' onClick='openMessage(\'' . $place_id . 
'\')'>";
?>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.placeContainer').click(function () {
        $(this).attr(phpvar);
        var myKey = JSON.parse(phpvar);
        console.log(myKey);
    })
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any function that named "openMessage" in your project ?

Comment: Was before, just mixing together the copy, used a normal 
    function openMessage(ID) {} before.

Comment: @PaumaDregis Try to use ordinary function: openMessage(ID){ console.log(ID); }. What does it print?

Comment: I did, it just prints out the last number in the foreach loop

Comment: @PaumaDregis Do `onClick` attributes have different values when calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

PHP Code :

```
<?php
foreach ($places as $place) {
    $place_id = json_encode($place['id']);
    echo "<div class='placeContainer' data-id='".$place_id."'>";
?>
```

JS Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.placeContainer').click(function () {
        var myKey = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(myKey);
    })
});
```

Comment: or `$(this).data('id');`